# Load the exported model into Apache Spark

Tags: python, pyspark

I use colab for load a trained model into apache spark

first I load a model

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model_TechnicalIndecator.h5")
model.save("bi_lstm_saved_model")
```

then I want to load the exported model into Spark

```
from pyspark.ml import PipelineModel

model_path = "bi_lstm_saved_model"
bi_lstm_model = PipelineModel.load(model_path)
```

but it give me this error:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o105.partitions.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/content/bi_lstm_saved_model/variables/saved_model.pb/metadata
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:304)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:244)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:332)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:291)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:291)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike.partitions$(JavaRDDLike.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Input path does not exist: file:/content/bi_lstm_saved_model/variables/saved_model.pb/metadata
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:278)
... 25 more

It seems the path to the saved model directory is incorrect or the directory does not exist , Why is this happening and how fix it